# Two layouts for same graph in d3.js?

Tags: d3.js

Can i have two layouts running in same graph , one layout for one subgraph and other layout for another subgraph of the same graph in d3.js ?
If yes please provide the links .

Comment: im not sure i understand the question. why dont you just have to seperate graphs using the same data ?

Comment: HI rekoDolph, What I mean is say I have data, var data = [10,20,30,40]; I want force layout to be applied on [10,20] and tree layout for [30,40] , the graph must be single graph but running two layouts

Answer (score 0):

i think you mean you want to create two graphs from the same data :

create two seperate pieces of data from your original data.

```
var data = [10,20,30,40];
var data1 = data.splice(0,1); //takes first two elements
var data2 = data.splice(2,3); //takes second two elements
```

now draw your graphs using the new pieces of data you have created using the original data :)

Comment: Hi rekoDolph, two graphs connected to each other by some links . Some nodes of first graph are connected to some nodes of another graph both running different layouts

Comment: If you split the data up and pass one set of data to the force layout and the other set to the tree layout maybe that will work. To be honest I've never done that before

Comment: I would do that, then, as I assume you want your two graphs linked, initialize the two graphs in the same svg and manually put in the links that will need to connect the two (as they won't be handled by either layout). Then remember to update these linking paths in the tick handler (or the relevant handler if the tree part of the graph is also dynamic).